# Jest with scss :export directive

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, jestjs

I have a javascript file that imports scss variables using the `:export` directive.

example.test.js

```js
import styles from './styles.scss';
const foo = styles.foo
```

styles.scss

```
:export {
   foo: "bar";
}
```

However if I run jest on this file, the `foo` variable is undefined. Is there any way to configure jest for this use case?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Never did, gave up on it :(

Answer (score 2):

Sure, into your *setupFile* of jest, add this:

```
jest.mock('path/your/styles.scss', () => {
    return{
        foo: "bar"
    }
})
```

Whenever you test a file which import this variable, jest will replace it with "bar"